# Definition of the probability distribution of a random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I have a vocabulary problem. I understand that a "probability distribution" is a function from a sigma algebra to the reals. But then what is a "probability distribution" in "the probability distribution of a random variable?"

Comment: The one that you have initially called as "probability distribution" is called a Random Variable. And "Probability distribution" is actually the measure induced on the $\mathbb R$ by the random variable.

Comment: @Miheer "The one that you have initially called as "probability distribution" is called a Random Variable." No.

Comment: @Did Of course, a random variable is a measurable function. Not just any function.

Comment: @Miheer Not sure I see your point. Anyway, the assertion that "a "probability distribution" is a function from a sigma algebra to the reals" is correct.

Comment: I am wrong. Sorry for the misinterpretation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A random variable is a measurable function $X:(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)\to(S,\mathcal S)$ between a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ and a measurable space $(S,\mathcal S)$. The probability distribution of $X$ is the unique measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal S$ such that $$\mu(B)=P(X^{-1}(B)),
$$ for every $B$ in $\mathcal S$. The measurability of the function $X$ is exactly the condition one needs to ensure that this formula makes sense.